# Track bluetooth LE keyring with RPi

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, beacon

I have bought a Chipolo (https://chipolo.net/) it is like other bluetooth low energy keyring (Tile, Keeper, Nut, ...)
I would like track it without the android application. I want to use a RPi for that.

If I put the device in association mode (press on it) I manage to discover it :

```
user@indigene:~ $ sudo hcitool lescan
LE Scan ...
C8:59:6F:2D:XX:XX Chipolo
```

I manage to make some request :

```
user@indigene:~ $ for d in $(sudo gatttool -t random --char-read --uuid 0x2a00 -b C8:59:6F:2D:XX:XX | sed 's,.*value: ,,'); do echo "0x$d" | xxd -r; done; echo
Chipolo

user@indigene:~ $ sudo gatttool -t random -b  C8:59:6F:2D:XX:XX --characteristics
handle = 0x0002, char properties = 0x02, char value handle = 0x0003, uuid = 00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle = 0x0004, char properties = 0x02, char value handle = 0x0005, uuid = 00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle = 0x0006, char properties = 0x02, char value handle = 0x0007, uuid = 00002a04-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle = 0x0009, char properties = 0x20, char value handle = 0x000a, uuid = 00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle = 0x000d, char properties = 0x1a, char value handle = 0x000e, uuid = 0000fff0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle = 0x0010, char properties = 0x0a, char value handle = 0x0011, uuid = 0000ffe0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle = 0x0012, char properties = 0x1a, char value handle = 0x0013, uuid = 0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle = 0x0016, char properties = 0x0a, char value handle = 0x0017, uuid = 0000ff00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle = 0x0018, char properties = 0x18, char value handle = 0x0019, uuid = 0000ff10-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle = 0x001b, char properties = 0x18, char value handle = 0x001c, uuid = 0000ff20-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

But when I leave the keyring without any command (for 2 minutes or more) it can't contact it anymore.

```
user@indigene:~ $ sudo gatttool -t random --char-read --uuid 0x2a01 -b C8:59:6F:2D:XX:XX | sed 's,.*value: ,,'
connect error: Connection refused (111)
```

Is there a way to request a connection or to pair with it ?
With the phone application, even if I let it for 5 minutes, when I get closer the keyring share data with the phone. Moreover I can make it ring with phone.

- Is there a way to recover/simulate this behaviour with a RPi ?
- Otherwise is there a way to analyse the bluetooth traffic between phone and keyring ?

Thanks in advance for your help,
BDR

Comment: You probably will need a packet sniffer if you want to reverse engineer the way a bluetooth device works.  http://www.ti.com/tool/CC2540EMK-USB

Comment: Did you manage to get this working?

Comment: Nope, I gave up

Comment: Have you tried paring the device? It might be using a random static BLE address, which means it only can be tracked by paired devices.